# How to create various buttons which get called on simple touch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton

I have to make an app in which there are around 20 buttons, if I switch from one button to another button without removing the touch(i.e. by dragging the touch) I want to call the function when I entered in that button's frame region.

For example:
[image]
when I drag touch from button's tag 10 to button's tag 11 then it should call button's tag 11 selector method.

Comment: add images on self.view then in your `touchBegin` method you can compare your image point with locationInView:self.view ... and give the method in if condition according to your image position ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not do it with `UIButtons`. But i have one suggestion for this may be it help you. Add `Images` instead of `Buttons` set those `userIntractionEnable:NO` then in `touchesMoved` method you can get call your `@selector` methods by comparing with `X,Y` co-ordinates.

I wrote a small code for this -

```
//I added your example image on my self.view with a view
//of 320x140 and set it userIntractionEnabled:NO
//Now in touchMoved: method did this..

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    //checking the touch is in self.view or not
    if([touch view] == self.view)
    {
        //This is like a 2D array, So you have to follow row and column pattern.
        if((pt.y>=0.0 && pt.y<=70.0))//For First Row
        {
            //These 7 are FirstRow Columns
            if(pt.x>=0.0 && pt.x<=45.0){
             NSLog(@"Method - 10");
            }
               if(pt.x>=46.0 && pt.x<=90.0){
                NSLog(@"Method - 11");
            }
            if(pt.x>=91.0 && pt.x<=135.0){
                NSLog(@"Method - 12");
            }

            if(pt.x>=136.0 && pt.x<=180.0){
                NSLog(@"Method - 13");
            }

            if(pt.x>=181.0 && pt.x<=225.0){
                NSLog(@"Method - 14");
            }

            if(pt.x>=226.0 && pt.x<=270.0){
                NSLog(@"Method - 15");
            }

            if(pt.x>=271.0 && pt.x<=315.0){
                NSLog(@"Method - 16");
            }

        }
        //Row change this is for Second Row
        if((pt.y>=71.0 && pt.y<=140.0))
        {
            //These 7 are SecondRow Columns
            if(pt.x>=0.0 && pt.x<=45.0){
            NSLog(@"Method - 17");
            }
            if(pt.x>=46.0 && pt.x<=90.0){
                NSLog(@"Method - 18");
            }
            if(pt.x>=91.0 && pt.x<=135.0){
            NSLog(@"Method - 19");
            }

            if(pt.x>=136.0 && pt.x<=180.0){
                NSLog(@"Method - 20");
            }

            if(pt.x>=181.0 && pt.x<=225.0){
            NSLog(@"Method - 21");
            }

            if(pt.x>=226.0 && pt.x<=270.0){
            NSLog(@"Method - 22");
            }

            if(pt.x>=271.0 && pt.x<=315.0){
                NSLog(@"Method - 23");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Hope this will help you !!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should register event with below way.

```
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
```